# Google Fit Android SDK Programmatically fetch

Tags: android, google-fit

i want fetch month wise data for entire year But not able get it directly. Please review my stuff and let me know if any option.

```
DataReadRequest mDataReadRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
.read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
.bucketByTime(30,TimeUnit.DAYS)
.setTimeRange(start, end, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.enableServerQueries()
.build();
```

Comment: Let us know if any other way

Comment: refer this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881055/get-all-activities-and-activities-info-from-google-fit-rest-api